# $h!\:\!(p-1-h)! \equiv (-1)^{h+1}\!\pmod{p}$ [Wilson Reflection Formula]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that $p$ is a prime. Suppose further that $h$ and $k$ are non-negative integers such that
$h + k = p − 1$.

I want to prove that $h!k! + (−1)^h \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

My first thought is that by Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, and $h!k!$ divides $(p-1)!$ (definition of a binomial). Where would I go from here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the fact that

$$h! = (-1)^h (p-1)(p-2) \dots (p-h) \mod p$$

Comment: Ah, so h!k! becomes [(-1)^h](p-1)! mod p, which is just -(-1)^h.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

**Generally** $\!\! $ Wilson's theorem $\,\Rightarrow\,$ *every* complete system of representatives $\,r_i\,$ of $\rm\color{#c00}{nonzero}$ remainders mod $\,p\,$ has product $\equiv -1,\,$ by $\,r_i\equiv i\,\Rightarrow\,\displaystyle  \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} r_i\equiv \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} i \equiv (p\!-\!1)!\equiv -1,\,$ by inductive extension of the  [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). In particular [this is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242) for any sequence of $\,p\,$ consecutive integers with its unique $\rm\color{#c00}{multiple}$ of $\,p\,$ removed. OP is the special case below $$\, \underbrace{\color{#90f}{-h},\,-h\!+\!1,\ldots,\color{#0a0}{-1}}_{\!\!\textstyle\equiv\,\color{#90f}{k\!+\!1},\,k\!+\!2,\cdots,\color{#0a0}{p\!-\!1}}\!\!\!\!,\require{cancel}\color{#c00}{\cancel{0}\!,} 1,2,\ldots, k\ \ \ \text{with product}\ \ (-1)^h h!\,k!\,\equiv\, -1\qquad$$

since $\,\color{#90f}{-h\equiv k\!+\!1}\,$ by $\,h\!+\!k\!+\!1\equiv p\equiv 0$

**Remark** $ $ This is slight reformulation of the Wilson reflection formula [mentioned yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23823/need-help-to-find-remainder-when-525-is-divided-by-31/23875#23875)

$$ k! = (p\!-\!1\!-\!h)! \,\equiv\, \frac{(-1)^{h+1}}{h!}\!\!\pmod{\! p},\,\ \ 0\le h < p\,\ {\rm prime}\qquad $$

**for example**  $\ \ h!^2 ≡ (−1)^{h+1} \pmod p\ $ for $\ h = (p-1)/2$