# In a congruence are the numbers remainders or residues?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, terminology, definition

If we have $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ then $a$ and $b$ are congruent to each other modulo $n$, correct?

What do we "call" $a$ and $b$? Because sometimes these numbers can be negative. Would they be remainders? Residues? Do we say these remainders (residues?) belong to the same "congruence class mod $n$"? Are remainders and residues synonymous?

Trying to get the terminology / lingo right here. When do we use which words? How do we describe what all this notation is representing / saying?

Comment: Yes; see [congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Definition_of_congruence_relation) : "two numbers $a$ and $b$ are said to be *congruent modulo* $n$". $a$ and $b$ are *numbers* and $n$ is called the *modulus* of the congruence.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ remainders? Residues?

Comment: "Like any congruence relation, congruence modulo $n$ is an equivalence relation, and the equivalence class of the integer $a$, denoted by $a_n$, is the set $\{ \ldots, a − 2n, a − n, a, a + n, a + 2n, \ldots \}$. This set, consisting of the integers congruent to a modulo $n$, is called the *congruence class* or *residue class* or simply *residue* of the integer $a$, modulo $n$."

Comment: Thus, *residue* of $a$ *modulo* $n$ is the set of all integers *congruent to* $a$ *modulo* $n$.

Comment: Huh for some reason I thought residue meant like remainder or a single number and not a set of integers, interesting. Is there a word for a given integer taken from the residue of $a$ mod $n$?

Comment: *reminder* is pertinent because $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $n$ exactly when they have the same reminder when divided by $n$. Thus, the *conguence class* (or *residue*) contains all numbers that have the same reminder.

Comment: @Sean "residue" is an overloaded (ancient) term. It can mean either a representative of a congruence class or the entire class. It can also mean "congruent", e.g. older texts often write "$b$ is a residue of $a$ modulo $n$" for $a\equiv b\pmod{n}.\,$  It predates modern (abstract) algebra so one can't expect it to be completely consistent with modern syntax and semantics.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Does it make sense to say that a negative number can have a positive/negative remainder? For example $-10$ divided by $7$ might have remainder $-3$ or remainder $4$?

Comment: @Sean remainders typically denote normal / canonical reps, e.g. least nonnegative or least magnitude (signed). reps, e.g. $\bmod 5$  they are $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ or $\{ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 \}. $ More generally we can use any complete systems of incongruent reps

Comment: We have that $-10$ divided by $7$ gives a *quotient* $q$ and a *reminder* $r$. The rule is : $7 \times q+r=-10$.

Comment: See the post : [negative number divided by positive number, what would be remainder?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623449/negative-number-divided-by-positive-number-what-would-be-remainder)

Comment: And see [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).