# What does it mean to say $x_{1} mod -x_{2}$ or $-x_{1} mod x_{2}$ when $x > 0$

Tags: arithmetic

I understand that $x_{1} \ mod \ x_{2} : x > 0$ is the remainder after dividing $x_{1}$ by $x_{2}$ ex: $5 \ mod \ 256 = 5$
but what does it mean to say $-x_{1} \ mod \ x_{2} : x > 0$ or $-5 \ mod \ 256$, I thought that it will be $-5$ but it's $251$, also the other way $x_{1} \ mod \ -x_{2} : x > 0$ or $5 \ mod \ -256$.

Comment: Also [negative number divided by positive number, what would be remainder?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623449/negative-number-divided-by-positive-number-what-would-be-remainder/623463#623463)

Comment: thank you I will check them