# Remainder of $35! $ when divided by $41$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I use $p=41 $ is a prime, so

$\begin{align}
(41-1)! &\equiv -1 \mod 41\\
(40)! &\equiv -1 \mod 41\\
40\times39\times38\times37\times36\times(35)! &\equiv -1 \mod 41\\
(-1)\times(-2)\times(-3)\times(-4)\times(-5)\times(35)! &\equiv -1 \mod 41\\
120(35)! &\equiv +1 \mod 41\\
(-3)(35)! &\equiv +1 \mod 41\\
(3)(35)! &\equiv  -1 \mod 41 \\
(3)(35)! &\equiv  -42 \mod 41 \ \to \div 3
\\(35)! &\equiv  -14\equiv 27 \mod 41 \\
\end{align}$

IS my work true ?
   can anyone says another idea ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You used a special case of the [Wilson Reflection Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2413454/242)

Comment: "IS my work true?" [Use a CAS to check your anwer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=35!+mod+41)

Comment: @miracle173 That CAS does not tell him whether the passages are correct or not.

Comment: you might want to explain how you computed the inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb Z/41 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @LeG He used $\,3x \equiv 3(-14)\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv -14,\,$ which is true for any modulus coprime to $3$ (since then, by Bezout, $3$ is invertible so cancellable). $\ \ $

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Doesn't it? I think each line can be verified by the CAS. What "passage" can't be checked by the CAS?

Comment: Do you realize that putting {curly braces} around {\equiv} is why you didn't have proper spacing? And using \text{mod } rather than \mod or \bmod is why you had to add spacing manually?

Comment: Personally I prefer \pmod{41} for formulas like this, but perhaps not everyone expects to see parentheses there.

Comment: Updated link to the [Wilson Reflection Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24131/242)  (prior thread was deleted)

Answer (score -1):

with a simple division, $$35!\equiv 27(mod41)$$