# Proving that $(p-3)!+2^{p-2} \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ p)$ if $p \geq 3$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p \geq 3$ be a prime number.

How to prove that $(p-3)!+2^{p-2} \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ p)$?

My idea was to use Wilson's theorem:

Since $p$ is a prime it follows that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ p)$.

$\Rightarrow 1 \cdot \cdot \  \cdot (p-2)(p-3)+2^{p-2} \equiv -1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ p)$

Then $1 \cdot \cdot \  \cdot (p-2)(p-3)+2^{p-2} +1 \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ p)$

Now I'm not sure what to do next. Is this way right or how can it be shown correctly?

Comment: **Hint** $ $ By [Wilson reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24095/242) $(p\!-\!3)! \equiv -1/2\,$ and $\,1/2 \equiv 2^{\large\, p-2}\,$ by little Fermat (or scale it by $\,(p\!-\!1)(p\!-\!2)\equiv 2$ to eliminate modular fractions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Wilson,
$$-1\equiv(p-1)!=(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)!\equiv 2\,(p-3)!\pmod p$$
and by Fermat
$$1\equiv 2^{p-1}=2\times 2^{p-2}\pmod p.$$
So
$$0\equiv2((p-3)!+2^{p-2})\pmod p.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just muck.

Bearing in mind $p-2,p-1 \equiv 2, 1 \pmod p$ and the $\pm2^{p-1} \equiv \pm1\pmod p$ and that $\gcd(2,p)=1$ so $2^{-1}\pmod p$ exists and is meaningful.....

$(p-1)! \equiv (p-3)!(p-2)(p-1)\equiv (p-3)!\cdot 2\pmod p$.

And noting Wilsons Th.  $(p-1)! \equiv -1\pmod p$ then

$(p-3)!\cdot 2 \equiv -(2^{p-1})\pmod p$

$(p-3)!\equiv -(2^{p-1})\cdot 2^{-1} \equiv -2^{p-2} \pmod p$ and that's it

$(p-3)! +2^{p-2} \equiv 0 \pmod p$ we are done.

What does this *mean*?  Well, if it means anything significant I missed it as all I did was muck about with well, known identities.