# Help understanding two theorems on primes and residue systems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

My textbook lists two theorems and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to interpret them. I don't need a proof; I'm only trying to figure out what information I'm being told by each theorem.

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $a$ be an integer not divisible by $p$; that is, $gcd(a,p)=1$. Then $\{a,2a,3a,...,pa\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $p$

So for this first theorem, I believe the canonical complete residue system $p$ would be $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$. So the set $\{a,2a,3a,...,pa\}$ would be the integers that satifsy the congruences, $a\equiv0 \space (mod \space p), 2a\equiv1 \space (mod \space p), 3a\equiv2 \space (mod \space p),...,pa\equiv (p-1) \space (mod \space p)$.

Is my interpretation correct?

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $a$ be an integer not divisible by $p$. Then,
>
> $a\cdot2a\cdot3a\cdot...\cdot(p-1)a\equiv1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot...\cdot(p-1) \space (mod \space n)$

For this second theorem, is this theorem telling me that I can decompose congruence integers into products of primes?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "So the set {a,2a,3a,...,pa} would be the integers that satifsy the congruences, a≡0 (mod p),2a≡1 (mod p),3a≡2 (mod p),...,pa≡(p−1) (mod p)."  They don't have to be (and actually *can't*) be in order.  The theorem is saying $a\equiv k_1\pmod p$ for *some* $k_1\in\{0,1,2....,p-1\}$ (but *not* $0$) and $2a\equiv k_2\pmod p$ for some $k_2\in\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ but $k_2\ne k_1$ (and if $a\not\equiv 1$ then $2a\not \equiv 2$... but that's not stated in the theorem). For example if $p=5$ and $a=7$ then $\{7,14,21,28,35\}\equiv\{2,4,1,3,0\}$ respectively.

Comment: Second Theorem is just saying that as $\{a,2a,3a,.....,(p-1)a\}$ is a residue system with every element bot the $0$ one.  ($ap\equiv a\times 0 \equiv 0$ of course) then $\{a,2a,3a,....,(p-1)a\}$ is equivalent to $\{1,2,3,....,p-1\}$ (but not in order!) then product of one set will be congruent to the product of the other set. This is a trivial result if think of it that way, but it means $a^{p-1}(p-1)!\equiv (p-1)!\pmod p$ which implies (if we could do division, which we can't; or if we know $(p-1)!\equiv 1\pmod p$ which we don't know...yet) then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$. Which is FLT.(almost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what does it mean.

A complete residue system $\mod p$.  What's that?

If you compare any integer $n \pmod p$ that are only $p$ options.  Either $n\equiv 0\pmod p$ or $n\equiv 1 \pmod p$ or $n\equiv 2 \pmod p$ or ...... or $n\equiv p-1\pmod p$.

So the list $\{0,1,2,.....,p-1\}$ is called a complete residue system because it contains a representation, a *residue*, for every case.

But that there nothing special about choosing just those (the smallest non-negative) residues.  We could have chosen any $\{r_1, r_2, ....., r_p\}$ so that every integer is equivalent to one of them (and we can list them in any order).

For example to find a complete residue system $\mod 6$ we can represent all the integers that have remainder of $0$ by $78$.  (Because $6|78$).  And we can represent all the integers that have a remainder of $2$ with $-22$ (because $-22 = -4*6 + 2$).  And we can represent all the integers that have remainder of $5$ with $647$ (because $647 = 642 + 5=6*107 + 5$) and so on.

So $\{78, -22, 647, 3001, -2,10\}$ is a complete residue system $\pmod 6$ because every interger is congruent to exact one of those $\pmod 6$. (test them: $$0\equiv 78\pmod 6; 1\equiv 3001 \pmod 6; 2\equiv -22\pmod 6; 3\equiv -2\pmod 6; 4\equiv 10\pmod 6; 5\equiv 647\pmod 6; 6\equiv 78\pmod 6; 7\equiv 3001\pmod 6$$ and so on. [they just cycle and cycle through].

(Admittedly, it's a fairly irrelevant and awkward way to represent them... but it does represent all $6$ possible congruences.)

So the theorem is saying:  If $p$ is a prime and $a$ is a number that .... isn't a multiple of $p$... then the set $\{a, 2a, 3a,.... , pa\}$ is a complete residue system $\mod p$ and that every integer is congruent to exactly one of those number.

For example:  $\mod 7$ and the number $3$ we'd have $\{3,6,9,12,15,18,21\}$ is a complete residue system.

And if we test it.  $$0\equiv 21 \pmod 7; 1\equiv 15\pmod 7; 2\equiv 9\pmod 7; 3\equiv 3 \pmod 7; 4\equiv 18\pmod 7; 5\equiv 12\pmod 7; 6\equiv 6\pmod 7; 7\equiv 21 \pmod 7; 8\equiv 15\pmod 7$$ and so on....

We could to it with *any* number (as long as it's not a multiple of $7$).  For example...... $93$....

$\{93, 186, 279, 372, 465, 558,651\}$ should work.  Does it?  I'm sure it does because I have complete faith in the theorem but looking at that I'd have no idea if it weren't for the theorem but:

$651 = 7*93$ that was a gimme; $372=53*7 + 1$ and $93=7*13+2$ and $465=7*67+3$ and $186=7*26+4$ and $558 = 7*79+5$ and $279=7*39 +6$ and so on.

It does work.

Comment: I know it's a heavy-handed approach, but writing out all the congruences modulo $p$ for your examples really helped me see what pattern was actually occurring.

Comment: @BobbyB You are supposed to have already had practice with complete residue systems before tackling these problems. My guess in comments on my answer appears appears to be  correct - you are putting the cart before the horse. It is absolutely crucial to be sure you understand prior topics before moving forward to topics depending on such. Mathematical exposition exploits these dependencies to the hilt.

Comment: My issue was not understanding complete residue systems. I've asked questions already on the basics of complete residue systems and received some great answers. In fact, my understanding of the first theorem was nearly correct. Fleablood's answer simply filled in the pieces I was missing with his well detailed examples. The language of modular arithmetic can be very confusing for beginners as to what literal arithmetic is actually occurring. Formal definitions need to be tied together with simple and direct examples, not a flurry of abstract terms. It's hard to find those examples.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have misunderstood both. Let's consider a simple special case:  $\,a=2,\, p=5.\,$ i.e. we consider the doubling map $\,n\to 2n\bmod 5\,$ whose action is as follows.

$\qquad\qquad\bmod 5\!:\,\ \begin{align}&2\{\color{#c00}1,2,3,\color{#0a0}4\} \\ 
                       \equiv\, &\ \ \{\color{#c00}2,4,1,\color{#0a0}3\}\end{align} $

i.e. $\ \ \ \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\begin{align}2\cdot \color{#c00}1&\equiv\color{#c00} 2\\ 2\cdot 2&\equiv 4\\ 2\cdot 3&\equiv 1\\ 2\cdot \color{#0a0}4&\equiv\color{#0a0}3  \end{align}\,$

Multiplying them all yields product of all on LHS  is congruent to product of all om RHS, i.e.

$\quad\qquad\qquad\begin{align}&(2\cdot\color{#c00} 1)(2\cdot 2)(2\cdot 3)(2\cdot\color{#0a0} 4)\\[.1em]
\equiv &\ \ \, (\color{#c00}2)\, \cdot\,  (4)\,\cdot\, (1)\,\cdot\, (\color{#0a0}3)\\[.1em] \equiv&\ \ \,4!\,\equiv -1\end{align}\,$ by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

*That's* what the theorem is telling you (and how it is proved).

**Remark** $ $ The key idea is: $\,\gcd(a,p)\!=\!1\Rightarrow$ the map $\,x\to ax\,$ is *invertible* $\!\bmod p\,$ so it is a *bijection*, so it simply *permutes* the complete set of nonzero residues $\,1,2,\ldots,p\!-\!1,\,$ which does not alter their product $\,(p\!-\!1)!,\,$ e.g. above the doubling map permuted $\,\color{#c00}1,2,3,\color{#0a0}4\ $ to $\ \color{#c00}2,3,1,\color{#0a0}3$.

The multuiplication is  a congruence generalization of the fact that equal finite sets of integers have equal products, by replacing "equal" by "congruent" (congruence can be viewed as a generalized equality - in fact it becomes an equality if we work in the quotient ring $\,\Bbb Z_p\,$ of cosets $\,[k] = k+p\Bbb Z)$

For another common example of this idea see the [Wilson reflection formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24131/242) where the permutation arises from an *additive* shift by $\,a\,$ (vs. *multiplicative* scaling by $\,a)$.

Comment: This explanation is beyond my current level of number theory. Invertibility, bijection, and permutation has not been discussed yet in my textbook. I'm at the very basic introduction to Fermat's Little Theorem and it's proof whereby these theorems are simply meant to help with that introduction.

Comment: @BobbyB Then simply ignore that paragraph - it is not needed in order to understand the example. Ignore the downvote too - it has nothing to do with *mathematiucs*

Comment: No, the down vote was warranted because your answer is not useful for beginners in Number Theory. You did not actually explain any of your ideas, you only stated other terms with the incorrect assumption that one would immediately know what you're talking about.

Comment: @BobbyB Not true, the main part of the answer is about as simple as one can get. If you can't follow that then you need to go back and review your notes / textbook. It seems as if perhaps you are trying to learn to run before you have learned to walk (esp. considering the major misunderstandings in your question).  If you explain precisely what you cannot follow in the first paragraph then I will be happy to elaborate.  I have no idea what that might be. fyi: many downvotes here are, alas, politically based and have nothing to do with the answer.